# Hadoop wordcount failing with very large file

Tags: hadoop

H all,

I am trying to run a wordcount job in Hadoop with a file of size 43 GB. Previously , I tested the system with a small file and job completed successfully. With the larger file, however, i am repeatedly getting this error:

```
14/07/28 15:50:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1406562550988_0001
14/07/28 15:50:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1406562550988_0001 running in uber mode : false
14/07/28 15:50:31 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/07/28 15:51:44 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/192.168.50.2:46671. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/07/28 15:51:45 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/192.168.50.2:46671. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/07/28 15:51:46 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/192.168.50.2:46671. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/07/28 15:52:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1406562550988_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1406562550988_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1406562550988_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1 due to: Exception from container-launch: 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)


.Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.
14/07/28 15:52:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

My core-site.xml file is given below:

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>fs.default.name</name>
                <value>hdfs://master:54310</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.replication</name>
                <value>3</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
                <value>file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-store/namenode</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
                <value>file:/mnt/datanode</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
                <value>yarn</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
                <value>master:54311</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
        <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
                <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
        </property>

</configuration>
```

I do not know what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I edited the yarn-site.xml file as follows:

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
        <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
                <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
                <value>
                        $HADOOP_CONF_DIR,
                        $HADOOP_INSTALL/share/hadoop/common/*,
                        $HADOOP_INSTALL/share/hadoop/common/lib/*,
                        $HADOOP_INSTALL/share/hadoop/hdfs/*,
                        $HADOOP_INSTALL/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*,
                        $HADOOP_INSTALL/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,
                        $HADOOP_INSTALL/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*,
                        $HADOOP_INSTALL/share/hadoop/yarn/*,
                        $HADOOP_INSTALL/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*
                </value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

My stderr file now shows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/service/CompositeService
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Can you edit and include the stderr of the logs of the job please?

Comment: The edits have been added

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: And what is output of `echo $HADOOP_CONF_DIR`? And `echo $HADOOP_INSTALL`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems hadoop jars are not visible. Please check $HADOOP_CONF_DIR, $HADOOP_HOME, $HADOOP_INSTALL and $YARN_HOME environment variables. Or specify direct lib paths in yarn-site.xml.